# What are some great economic reforms from the Middle Ages / the Ancient History?

Tags: history, history-economic-thought, economic-history

Is there any great economic structural reforms, which date back to the Middle Ages or to the Ancient times?

Comment: Do they have to be legal reforms (change minimum wage) or could they be cultural (perception of charging interest)?

Comment: @BKay Any examples of structural reforms would be greatly welcomed :) I'm not looking for a single government measure, but a system level measure.